# Platform extension documentation URL

Tags: here-api

I need to find the documentation for the Here Layers. There used to be under this URL (https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/) , but apparently they removed it and now it redirect's to another URL. Does anyone know the new URL for the platform-data extension documentation(I have been searching a hole day but can't find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform data extension is the legacy name for the fleet telematics advance data set.you can find HERE layers documentation from these url-

https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/resource-layers.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/maps?url_root=pde.api.here.com